# formulario que suma el valor de un select

Tags: javascript

buenas tardes y gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda ante mis dudas.

Tengo un formulario que multiplica valores y suma los totales de las filas a medida que estas se van incrementando. El problema que tengo es que no sé como sumar el valor del option seleccionado en el select y que este se actualize tambien con respecto al número de filas en tiempo real. Tambien quiero mostrar el total completo con un botón en vez de en un input y que sume lineas dependiendo del tipo de option elegido; es decir las lineas que contienen un tipo de valor del option por un lado y las lineas que contienen otro tipo de option, por otro

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var length = $('.one').length;
        var cloned = $(this).closest('.one').clone(true);        
        cloned.appendTo("#mainDiv").find('.sno').val(length + 1);
        cloned.find(':input:not(".sno")').val(" ");
        var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
        calculate(parent);
    });
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
        $(this).parents(".one").remove();
        calculate(parent);
    });
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.tbs, .ndiscos', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
    calculate(parent);
})


function calculate(e){
    
    var tbs = +$(e).find('.tbs').val(); //Valor de tbs
    var ndiscos = +$(e).find('.ndiscos').val();//Valor  del nº de Discos
    var sum = 0;
    $(e).find('.total').val(tbs*ndiscos);

    $('.total').each(function(i,e){
        sum += +$(e).val();        
    });

    $('#Grand').val(sum);
};
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
   
   <div id="mainDiv">

    <div class="row one">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <select class="tipoDisco calculaselect" id="tipoDisco" name="tipoDisco" data-rule-required="true" title="Choose Group Size...">
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>   
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="text" name="tbs" class="tbs">
                <label>TBS</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" name="ndiscos" class="ndiscos">
                <label>Nº de Discos</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="text" name="total" class="total">
                <label for="total">total</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="input-field col s1"> <a href="#" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light add ">Add<i class="mdi-content-add"></i></a>

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s1"> <a href="#" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light delete ">Remove<i class="mdi-content-clear"></i></a>

            </div>
            </div>
            
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" name="Grand" id="Grand">
    <label for="net_rate">Grand Total</label>
    </div>
</div>




                            </div>


 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta se puede resolver por partes:

Con respecto a cómo sumar el valor del `option` seleccionado en un select, el propio elemento [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) te provee de un atributo `value` al que puedes acceder. Este atributo te devuelve el valor del `option` que sea seleccionado.

Un ejemplo en vanillaJS sería:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#my-select');


selectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log(selectElement.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Primera Opción</option>
  <option value="2">Segunda Opción</option>
  <option value="3">Tercera Opción</option>
</select>
```

y en jQuery el mismo ejemplo sería:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#my-select', () => {
  const value = $('#my-select').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Primera opción</option>
  <option value="2">Segunda opción</option>
  <option value="3">Tercera opción</option>
</select>
```

Con respecto a cómo actualizar el valor de un select en "tiempo real" sencillamente con hacerte una función que actualice el valor del select automáticamente seleccionará el `option` que tú le indiques si existe.

De nuevo, un ejemplo en vanillaJS:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#my-button');
const select = document.querySelector('#my-select');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  select.value = 2;
})
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>

<button id="my-button">MI BOTÓN</button>
```

Y el mismo ejemplo en jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('click', $('#my-button'), () => {
  $('#my-select').val(2);
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>

<button id="my-button">MI BOTÓN</button>
```

Con respecto a la suma de valores en un botón, sencillamente puedes cambiar el tipo del input a `button` añadiéndo al tag `type="button"`.

```html
<input id="my-regular-input" value="SOY UN INPUT NORMAL">
<input id="my-type-button-input" value="SOY UN INPUT TYPE BUTTON" type="button">
```

Con respecto a la suma de valores separadas por tipos es probable que la estructura que sigues actualmente no te vaya a ser completamente útil.

La idea que se me ocurre es que podrías generar por cada "grupo de elementos" un objeto y operar con esos objetos. Un ejemplo breve podría ser:

```js
const getAllValues = () => {
  const values = [];

  const inputGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.input-group');
  const inputGroupsArray = Array.from(inputGroups);
  
  inputGroupsArray.forEach((inputGroup) => {
    const inputGroupObject = {};
    
    inputGroupObject.type = inputGroup.querySelector('.type').value;
    inputGroupObject.value = inputGroup.querySelector('.value').value;
    
    values.push(inputGroupObject);
  });
  
  return values;
}

const getAlbums = values => values.filter(element => element.type === "1")
const getRecopilatories = values => values.filter(element => element.type === "2")
const getDiscographies = values => values.filter(element => element.type === "3")

const getTypeTotal = elements => elements.reduce((prev, curr) => parseInt(prev.value) + parseInt(curr.value));

const updateGrandTotalValue = () => {
  const allValues = getAllValues();
  const grandTotalButton = document.querySelector('#grand-total');
  
  const albumsCollection = getAlbums(allValues);
  const recopilatoriesCollection = getRecopilatories(allValues);
  const discographiesCollection = getDiscographies(allValues);
  
  const albumsPartialTotal = getTypeTotal(albumsCollection);
  const recopilatoriesPartialTotal = getTypeTotal(recopilatoriesCollection);
  const discographiesPartialTotal = getTypeTotal(discographiesCollection);
  
  const buttonValue = `Grand Total: Álbum: ${albumsPartialTotal}, Recopilatorio: ${recopilatoriesPartialTotal}, Discografía: ${discographiesPartialTotal}`;
  
  grandTotalButton.value = buttonValue;  
}

updateGrandTotalValue();
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1">Álbum</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3">Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="11" readonly>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1" selected>Álbum</option>
    <option value="2">Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3">Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="22" readonly>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1">Álbum</option>
    <option value="2">Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="33" readonly>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1">Álbum</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3">Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="44" readonly>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1" selected>Álbum</option>
    <option value="2">Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3">Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="55" readonly>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="type">
    <option value="1">Álbum</option>
    <option value="2">Recopilatorio</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Discografía</option>

  </select>
  <input class="value" value="66" readonly>
</div>

<input id="grand-total" type="button" value="Grand Total: Álbum: 0, Recopilatorio: 0, Discografía: 0">
```

Estas son las ideas que se me ocurren para solucionar tu casuística. ¡Espero que te sirvan!

Comment: Ok, muchas Gracias por tu ayuda! voy a probarlo